# Add decimal digits to number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to add a defined number of decimal digits to a certain number?

I have two rows in my worksheet. In the first column I have digits from 1 to 9 and in the second column I want to equal the decimal digits of 99 with the digit in the first column.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99.9 |
| 2 | 99.99 |
| 3 | 99.999 |
| 4 | 99.9999 |
| 5 | 99.99999 |

Could someone provide me with a formula in Excel for this problem. I would rather not use VBA because the problem seems rather trivial.

Any help is appreciated.

I tried the formula =9*1/(10^A4) for the first row (second column). I got the output below which is not quite what I was looking for

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 0.09 |
| 3 | 0.009 |
| 4 | 0.0009 |
| 5 | 0.00009 |

Comment: Try: `=100-1/(10^A2)` or you could spill `=100-1/(10^A2:A6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether you are looking for this or not, posted to show a screenshot of your expectation.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=100-1/(10^A2:A6)
```

---

If you are using older versions, then:

```
=100-1/(10^A2)
```

---

Comment: Cool stuff! Upvote from me.

Comment: @P.b Sir, it looks more like a math problem rather than an `Excel`

Comment: Still I like it

Comment: Aww. Thank you very much =) Also just realized i could enter in Excel in this way as well: `=1E2-1/(10^A2:A6)` where `1E2` converts to `100` strange